# Generate random numbers between range using std::binomial_distribution

Tags: c++, random, sparse-matrix

I created a function to generate sparse matrix, however the random generator only generates only values of **1s** and I need to make it generate numbers in a specific range.

```
size_t spare_matrix_generator(int *M, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    gen.seed(time(NULL));

    std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(1, 0.5);

    size_t NNZ = 0;

    for (szie_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
    {
        M[i] = distribution(gen);
        std::cout << M[i] << " ";
        if (A[i] != 0)
            NNZ++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return NNZ;
}
```

A sample output of the above function would be as following, assuming **5x5** Matrix:

```
0 1 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: uniform int distribution? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Do you need to use the binomial distribution ? Or any random generator could do the trick ?

Comment: I need it to be binomial_distribution

Comment: Why `gen.seed(time(NULL));` when you have already seeded your generator with `random_device`? You undo the previous seeding like that and replace it with a much worse seed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was trying something .. it is not effecting the code logic thou .. it can be omitted in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numbers in [a, b], with a < b, the idea is to generate a random number with `std::binomial_distribution` between 0 and `b-a`, and to add `a` to the generated result to respect the input range [a, b]:

```
size_t spare_matrix_generator(int *M, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    gen.seed(time(NULL));
    int b = 12, a = 3;

    std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(b-a, 0.5);

    // To handle matrix sparsity
    float zero_prob = 0.8;
    std::mt19937 sparse_gen(rd() + 42);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> sparse_dist(0.0,1.0);

    size_t NNZ = 0;

    for (szie_t i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
    {
        if(sparse_dist(sparse_gen) > zero_prob){
            M[i] = a + distribution(gen);
        } else {
            M[i] = 0;
        }

        std::cout << M[i] << " ";
        if (M[i] != 0)
            NNZ++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return NNZ;
}
```

Comment: That works, however the sparsity of the matrix is lost

Comment: Does the sparsity of the matrix depends on something ?

Comment: I tested the code (my original code) many time with many different values for the two parameters of the   binomial_distribution .. my conclusion is that using 1 only  limits the output range into 1s and 0s only .. however choosing a different range say (10 - 5) will force the generator to generate all the possibilities of numbers between 10 and 5 (i.e. 4, 3, 2, 1, 5) .. so the  possibility that a 0 will appear (a.k.a making it sparse) will decrease than in the first case

Comment: Yes, one solution is to use another distribution to control the sparsity of the matrix. That way, you can decide the traction of non null elements you want. And, for these elements, you can generate random numbers as you wish.

Comment: now I understand your edit .. Thanks for the answer